# Phantom.js login instagram page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying use phantom.js to login in instagram website. My first approach was:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='username']").value = "Username";
document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value = "Pass";
```

But this code don't change da DOM.

My second approach:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("_kp5f7 _qy55y")[0].setAttribute("value", "Username");
document.getElementsByClassName("_kp5f7 _qy55y")[0].value = "Pass";
```

But when I inspect the network packages fields username and pass are blank.

Instagram login page: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/

Comment: have you set headers and credentials correctly? and the most important - are all those query selectors in context of a webpage?

Comment: what you are doing is correct, the problem lays outside the scope of provided code.

Comment: did you find the solution to th problem? I've been facing the same issue but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @RitikSaxena see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41478868/2715393

Comment: @Vaviloff it doesn't save 'instagram.png' in my current directory.

Comment: @RitikSaxena Please indicate the desired directory for saving image right inside `page.render` method. Like this: `page.render('/home/ritik/instagram.png');` or `page.render('C:\\Users\\Ritik\\instagram.png');`

Comment: @RitikSaxena I've solved the issue with script not working on Linux, please, see my [update/edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41478868/2715393) You don't have to go to all the hassle with SlimerJS and xvfb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: Please see edit below the answer**

I don't really think that

> PhantomJS can't handle that page

It's probably us not doing good enough of impersonation of a real browser.

A quick search for "instagram login phantomjs" found this neat solution that **works**: https://github.com/awener/instagram-login-phantomjs/blob/master/phan.js

It uses PhantomJS mechanism of simulating "real" keypresses and clicks.

Here's a copy of the script just in case.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var username = "myusername";
var password = "password";
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024 , height: 600 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36';

page.open('https:/instagram.com/accounts/login/', function() {

    var ig = page.evaluate(function() {
        function getCoords(box) {
            return  {
                x: box.left,
              y: box.top 
            };
        }   

        function getPosition(type, name) {
            // find fields to fill
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName(type);
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if(name && input[i].name == name)  return getCoords(input[i].getBoundingClientRect());
                else if(!name && input[i].className)    return getCoords(input[i].getBoundingClientRect()); // this is for login button
            }
        }
        return {
            user: getPosition('input', 'username'),
            pass: getPosition('input', 'password'),
            login: getPosition('button')
        };

     });

     // fill in data and press login
     page.sendEvent('click',ig.user.x, ig.user.y);
     page.sendEvent('keypress', username);

     page.sendEvent('click',ig.pass.x, ig.pass.y);
     page.sendEvent('keypress', password);
     page.sendEvent('click', ig.login.x, ig.login.y);

    // wait for response
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('/path/to/screenshot.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);

});
```

---

**Edit with explanation on how to run the script on Linux**

The reason this did not work on Debian/Ubuntu is SSL certificate issues.

There is a verbose mode telling about what PhantomJS is doing, when you run it with --debug=true CLI option. Using that I've found the cause of the problem:

```
[DEBUG] Network - SSL Error: "The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found"
[DEBUG] Network - SSL Error: "The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose"
[DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(SslHandshakeFailedError) ( "SSL handshake failed" ) URL: "https://instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1/scripts/polyfills/es5-sham.min.js/fc3c22cf2d67.js"
...
```

To avoid this type of problems you just have to run Phantomjs with another CLI argument telling it to ignore SSL errors:

```
/pth/to/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true /path/to/script.js
```

Comment: i've tested it, but unfortunately, the script is not working :'(

Comment: Please, be more specific in what way is it not working. I've tested on Win 7 x64 with PhantomJS 2.1.1 and the resulting `instagram.png` does contain what I see after login in Chrome.

Comment: `./phantomjs ins.js >/dev/stdout` - on Debian 8 (64 bit) doesn't work. phantomjs `2.1.1`

Comment: Again I ask: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does that mean that image is not created?

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't exit, doesn't generate `instagram.png`

Comment: Yes, there are issues. When run from an Ubuntu server, even a minimal example of opening login page and making a screenshot won't work. Interesting, will try to debug later.

Comment: I've run the script on Ubuntu15.04 but it didn't work. I added the following code `page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
 console.log(msg);
}` to check if it there is an issue with permissions to save the image, and added `console.log("done");` below `page.render`. It still doesn't work.