# Instagram login through Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've been tinkering around with Selenium and PhantomJS since a few hours now. I'm trying to write a script that logs in to Instagram. That's it. As simple as that.

Here's what I've got so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="password"]')
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_aj7mu _taytv _ki5uo _o0442"]')

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password!")

#test to see if input values are reflecting
print(username.get_attribute('value'))
print(password.get_attribute('value'))

#login
login_btn.click()
logged_in_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("logged-in")
not_logged_in_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("not-logged-in")

#to check if logged-in or not-logged-in
print(len(logged_in_class))
print(len(not_logged_in_class))


driver.quit()
```

The input values are reflecting correctly. There seems to be an issue with login. Could anyone throw light on this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use Chrome as webdriver.  PhantomJS based on Qt and not fully compatible with modern sites.

Comment: [Phantom.js login instagram page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467692/phantom-js-login-instagram-page/41472312)

Comment: I actually debugged the problem via the Chrome webdriver as I could see what was happening. With PhantomJS, I couldn't see anything at all. 

Turns out the code just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is an SSL error on that site, you need to use these command-line options:

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true --debug=true
```

You need to use [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, to find out, what's going wrong.