# How to run browser functionality on server?

Tags: javascript, java, php, python, linux

I have a web site and parsing some content from social media
or other web sites to keep information up to date. As you know **Instagram** won't
work with "beatifulSoup Python Parser" or maybe others just because you have to **log in**, and must be able to **run js**, *otherwise it won't load*. And it happens with others too.

For that reason i do run some js script on client side, using google **chrome console**, this script saves the data in **localStorage** which i do use after.

The problem is sometimes i do have a low speed internet, or i have to run this script with my pc, it takes a lot of time. Maybe not much but doing in every day time, it becomes really problematic.

I wanted to make this job on server side, there is always high internet speed, and i would be *able to start the script with my phone*, when ever
or where ever, and i am trying to figure out how to realize.

I need a browser on server side, which would run js, and just everything the **same as a client**.

1. Start a browser
2. Wait for a page load
3. run some js script

Most of the servers do not have the **graphic interface** and do return on terminal just **html code**.

But there is a lot of host services, java servers and more and more, not only apach or nginx. On java as i know you can **create a browser** of your own,
so it means kinda possible to run **browser function on server**.

The question is, is there any **ready tools** which i can just use, or maybe to write this kinda functionality, but using libraries, frameworks to be able to write it as fast as possible, not spending a lot of time. Because I am not working over, to create a browser on server side, i just want to be able to run some js.

I work with php, js, python. Java only SE and on the client. JavaEE has a lot of libraries and tons of abilities. Maybe somebody knows in which language
i could realize this. Any frameworks, or maybe on linux it is possible, or there is a host servers which can run as a client, some companies i think does this kind of staff to make some job automatically.

I was thinking about phantomjs or nodejs, but i am new for them, and i guess i would spend a lot of time with no result.

Any advices, links, opinions, ideas would help me a lot, Thanks!!!

[image]

Phantomjs does works, but you can't log in with Phantomjs, maybe because it doesn't keeps cookie or session data, or maybe there is no headers, so instead of using web **scraper** programs just use real browser on server

PhantomJS is really uneasy, inconvenient or whatever, for testing you do not get any information, it takes too long time, you can't run just js script.

```
page.evaluate(function() {

     setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("login").click(); console.log("click initialized"); }, 1000);
});
```

SetTimeout inside evaluate seems to not work, even check for that takes a lot of time

```
page.evaluateJavascript(function() {

});
```

evaluateJavascript gets stuck (it won't run phantom.exit(0)), you have to restart cmd and go to cd and type all comands again.

Very simple manupulations grows into huge problems. I don't know why phantomjs was created, was it only for just capturing or doing a really simple staff. Even parser from phantomjs is awfull. There is no tutorials, none of use. No graphic interface, the script inside evaluate seems like run js in not a proper way, it is really difficult to identify and learn how it is working inside. You don't have any access, any information, whenever it return an empty line or just none. No errors, just anything. Was it popular, i don't know, i heard before about phantomjs, seems like just nothing, ugly, no use.

I was thinking about webDriver for example selenium, there is no need to run selenium on client, running on server seems to be a little bit expensive. There is no hosting which would give you a vds with gui, not ubuntu server, because you need the browser.

---

> I realized that there is no solution

---

i have a script which works on js, and it has a multi functionality, not only parsing, kinda bot, which analyses user data, follows, unfollows, post the data, and runs throws the users. Question was "How to run browser functionality on server", i just wanted emulate browser by program starting for 100 of accounts on server at once, but this is not possible i guess. Maybe i will close the question with the solution of "There is no solution, you can't run browser on server". WebDriver usage is too expensive. There is no program, for webDrivers you could use at once Ex: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Yandex and seems that all, but they are also use a lot of RAM which is too expensive on VDS server.

Comment: This looks like a task for **API**, create an **API** for your website and then call it from your server to execute your function or if it is related to `Instagram` they would have an API for which can be accessed to get information.

Comment: @vikscool I am not sure about API, i am parsing different accounts which is bad, Instagram won't like it, and they ask tons of question, like where, why and how you will use it. At the end they just won't give permission

Comment: Instagram has an API to get your information, no need to scrape their website. Run a cronjob that periodically fetches the info you need from the API and save it to your server.

Comment: @kerbholz if it was only one account, or known account, yes this maybe would work, but the situation is i am running from one account to another, searching data, and doing a lot of staff by document.click kinda bot comparing the data, not just parse. phantomjs looks, it also i guess only loads a page, no more functionality. On Instagram js works great, because they do load pages with ajax. And the script runs a long time doing a lot of staffs. Only problem is sign in and load js, which many servers can't

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to login to **scrape** Instagram. Working with JS, I have used requests_html package that does the job for you. You could start with instagram_scraper(https://github.com/meetmangukiya/instagram-scraper) which is inspired by twitter-scraper(https://github.com/kennethreitz/twitter-scraper) by Kenneth Reitz who is the author of both requests and requests_html. The main idea is to scrape without tokens or logins

Both scripts has inspired me to create a **scraper** that does not require login. It is a good place to start, at least.

Updated 2018-09-22: I followed [Setting up a Digital Ocean server for Selenium, Chrome, and Python](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/servers/setting-up/) but on my own server. The trick is creating a fake display: See this from Jonathan, runs on server :)

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://nytimes.com')
print(driver.title)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce, but the situation is a little different, i have a script which works on js, and it has a multi functionality, not only parsing, kinda bot, which analyses user data, follows, unfollows, post the data, and runs throws the users. Question was "How to run browser functionality on server", i just wanted emulate browser by program starting for 100 of accounts on server, but this is not possible i guess. Maybe i will close the question with the solution of "There is no solution, you can't run browser on server". WebDriver usage is too expensive.

Comment: Ah! It is possible to run Selenium on Server :) I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), I have used this to complete many spiders that need login or js load operation.

You can log in using Phantomjs, and it can set cookie, session data and request headers. All you need to do is search the method, like this:
[phantomjs login Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467692/phantom-js-login-instagram-page)

when you using phantomjs, the most important thing is that everytime you want to do the next step, you must ensure the page or related elements was load finished. Because page or js load need speed time, sometimes you also need send extra args to get the page load, otherwise you can't start the next step without the related elements.

Comment: I was trying to get deeper into PhantomJS and it works and not the best way but it works. For example every time i need to log in, when ever i will start
evaluate. 
 I just learned that my hosting server "Beget" doesn't have ability to install phantomjs, i have ssh access but haven't any permissions for installation.
Advice, which hosting you are using, or is there any free hosting services where i could test and so.

Comment: @AsylzatAzaev if this hosting server belongs to you, I think you can find the Administrator/root account informations in your profile page, or you can ask the "Beget" or the ops of your company to tell you the Administrator/root account, then you can have permission to install what you need. If you want to test in your local, you can use virtualbox(free) or VMware Workstation(commercial) or docker(open source) to install the same system of your beget host server in your pc, then you can test whatever you want.

Comment: I think phantomjs wosn't solution for me, it is really hard to use, you log in, after you have been logged in, the script inside page.evaluate(function() { seems to run js or jquery script not correct, the problem also, it is really hard to identify, what is not working. No information, just a black screen, very uneasy for development, testing, running.

Comment: My script on js contains 1000 lines and it may run hours or more on my web browser. And there is a lot of manipulations document.getElementById("login").click() click events and a lot of jquery staff, exeptions and if statements, what does phantomjs, it only return a black screen and unpredictable behavior for 2 lines of code.

Comment: setTimeout inside evaluate seems to do not work, no logs. Phantomjs works page.sendEvent('keypress', username); and document.getElementById("login").click() do not works, it means js is not js in phantom, it has it is own reduced js ability for scripting. It may work for a really simple parser or screen capture, phantomjs i guess i will stop my researches 
 for phantomjs. Am i wrong?